# anychart stock - range selection with mm:ss resolution

Tags: anychart

i'm using anychart stock 8.1.0. I have a dataset with 24 hours of date with per-second resolution. I would like for only a small 30 seconds subset of that data to be shown/zoomed on load.

I could not find out how to do this so i tried adding a range selector option like below but i couldn't get that working either.

```
rangeSelector.ranges([{
        'text': 'Testing',
        'startDate': '2006 May 16 13:00:00',
        'endDate': '2006 May 16 13:00:30'
    }
```

If i use the range selector slider i can zoom as i require but how do i define this in code ?

So to recap i'd like

1. have the chart zoomed on load for a specific time range of type
   start-stop in format of `dd/MM/yyy mm:ss`
2. have range selector button options for various time ranges of same format as above.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can define your own custom periods for rangeSelector, but if you want to zoom to specific period on load you have to call selectRange() method after chart drawing. 
If you want to show only 30 seconds in the beginning of your series you should put the following line into your code:

```
chart.selectRange("second", 30, "first-date", true);
```

You can learn more about this method [here](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.charts.Stock#selectRange)
And find a similar example of using it [here](https://playground.anychart.com/api/charts/_samples/anychart.charts.Stock.selectRange_set_asUnit)

Comment: yes thanks i saw this but it's not clear how i can start at an arbitrary timestamp ? So i don't want to start at the beginning, i want to start "somewhere" of interest in the 24 hour dataset i.e. `yyyy-MM-dd hh:ss`. How you give an example of both the rangeSelector and this selectRange where the start/end can be explicitly specified with a timestamp as above please. thank you.

Comment: yes, you can specify any 30 seconds range manually like in the following example I prepared for you - https://playground.anychart.com/Wac2P1V6

Comment: ok thank you very much. I had tried this before but overlooked that my data is all in UTC and i was specifying the `chart.selectRange` also in UTC which does not work.. i have to give the time in my local time that corresponds to the relevant UTC time. e.g i'm GMT +8 so if i wanted to see a range of 18:00 i needed to use 02:00:00 in the range time. Bit confusing.

Comment: to solve this issue you should define inputDateTimeFormat and use parseDateTime() method inside the selectRange. I've modified the example to show you how it works - https://playground.anychart.com/aYqa41kQ    In future releases this behavior will be improved